# How to switch screens while having a persistent top menu?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy's screen manager to switch screens (specifically switch_to). What is the best practice for switching only part of the screen, while keeping a persistent top navigation menu that doesn't switch (as found in many app designs, such as the Facebook app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScreenManager doesn't have to be the root widget, e.g. you could have

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'permanent label'
    ScreenManager:
        ...
```

In this case the Label will be unaffected by changing the ScreenManager screen. You can do the same with whatever menu you use.